# Read data from Excel data by JSPDynpage

Tags: jsp, sap-enterprise-portal

I have created `JSPDynpage` component and I am trying to read Excel file using Apache POI 3.2 API.

I have followed the chapter "File Upload" in the guide "Running an Enterprise Portal > Core Development Tasks > HTML-Business for Java" in the SAP Help documentation (formerly   http://help.sap.com/saphelp_sm40/helpdata/en/63/9c0e41a346ef6fe10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm).

Error at the line `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fp);` (see code below):

> #getLocalizedMessage# C:\Documents and Settings\10608871\Desktop\test.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)

I have created the PAR file and deploying it on server.

Thanks in advance.

Aliya Khan.

My code:

```
    try 
{
 
FileUpload fu = (FileUpload) 
                        this.getComponentByName("myfileupload");

         //    this is the temporary file
         if (fu != null) {
             //    Output to the console to see size and UI.
             System.out.println(fu.getSize());
             System.out.println(fu.getUI());
             //    Get file parameters and write it to the console
             IFileParam fileParam = fu.getFile();
             System.out.println(fileParam);
             //    Get the temporary file name
             File f = fileParam.getFile();
             String fileName = fileParam.getFileName();
             //    Get the selected file name and write it to the console
             ivSelectedFileName = fu.getFile().getSelectedFileName();
File fp = new File(ivSelectedFileName);
  myLoc.errorT("#fp#"+fp);
  try {

  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fp);       //<============ ERROR HERE
 
  HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
  
  myLoc.errorT("#workbook#"+workbook);
//Get first sheet from the workbook
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  myLoc.errorT("#sheet#"+sheet);
                        
//
  } catch(Exception ioe) {
  myLoc.errorT("#getLocalizedMessage# " + ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem, i was  passing the worng parameter instead of f
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);